# How to create a template out of my customized launch.json in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

For my project, I have customized my *launch.json* file.

How can I save my own customized launch configuration as a template? Just like **C++ (GDB/LLDB)** template
So that I can re-use it easily every time I open a new folder(project).

I don't want to add it under [global launch configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_global-launch-configuration). Adding it there would start showing up my launch configurations even for other kind of projects where this launch configuration is inappropriate.

I wanted to have the same behavior that is achieved for **C++ (GDB/LLDB)** template. How is that achieved?

Edit - I have raised an enhancement request VSCode GitHub-
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/109234

Answer (score 0):

They are part of the debugger configuration in the language extension.

Way too much trouble to create an extension for this.

Just create a snippet for a `.json` file and use it while editing the `.vscode/launch.json`

**Edit:**

The file with the snippets should be `jsonc.json` (JSON with Comments)

or a workspace snippets file with the `scope` of the snippet set to `jsonc`

Comment: When you say - create a snippet do you mean to say - use _tasks_ to achieve this?

Comment: @DarshanL No a simple text snippet https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets

Comment: As an fyi, the snippet must be defined for jsonc, not json