# Can I create custom launch.json file in Vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there possibility to set up launch.json file in vscode  so that it launches with my configuration  every time? For example: I write in python and every time .vsocde directory is created with launch.json file it looks like this:

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [

    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal"
    }
]}
```

I have a few configurations I'd like to and I wonder whether there is a setting which would help me to edit this template launch file so that I don't have to edit it every time I create a new folder.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a template out of my customized launch.json in vscode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64440621/how-to-create-a-template-out-of-my-customized-launch-json-in-vscode)

Comment: Using Global launch configuration, https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_global-launch-configuration.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I'll look them up.