# Use Snippets in launch.json in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I have a few dev systems that I constantly connect to. I work on many different and new projects. I reset the systems so that connection details do not change.

Right now, every time I create a new project, I have to copy the launch.json from elsewhere, either using a text copy or file copy, depending on what I need. This got pretty tiring, so I thought I would create snippets for the various launch configs. Created my json snippets, tried them, but when using insert snippet within a launch.json, it says no snippets found. [That was the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64443401/6504973), but I can't get it to work.

If I try to insert the snippet in a different json file, it works immediately.

Is there something special I need to do so that I can insert snippets into the launch.json? I can't seem to find any information on that. I tried to look for a way to customize the config options, but outside of writing an extension to insert them, I could not figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the languageId of `tasks.json`, `settings.json` and `launch.json` is **JSON with Comments**

The short id is `jsonc`, so save your snippets in the `jsonc.json` file

If your active file is `launch.json` and you select **LowerLeft-Gear** | **User Snippets** you see a list with a `jsonc.json` suggestion.

Comment: Thank you, thank you so much. Should've been able to figure that one out.